# Qt - reading from a text file

Tags: qt

I have a table view with three columns; I have just passed to write into text file using this code

```
QFile file("/home/hamad/lesson11.txt");
if(!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
    QMessageBox::information(0,"error",file.errorString());
}
QString dd;

for(int row=0; row < model->rowCount(); row++) {
     dd = model->item(row,0)->text() +  ","
                 + model->item(row,1)->text() +  ","
                 + model->item(row,2)->text();

     QTextStream out(&file);
     out << dd << endl;
 }
```

But I'm not succeed to read the same file again, I tried this code but I don't know where is the problem in it

```
QFile file("/home/hamad/lesson11.txt");
QTextStream in(&file);
QString line = in.readLine();
while(!in.atEnd()) {

    QStringList  fields = line.split(",");

    model->appendRow(fields);

}
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 97):

You have to replace string line

```
QString line = in.readLine();
```

into *while*:

```
QFile file("/home/hamad/lesson11.txt");
if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    QMessageBox::information(0, "error", file.errorString());
}

QTextStream in(&file);

while(!in.atEnd()) {
    QString line = in.readLine();    
    QStringList fields = line.split(",");    
    model->appendRow(fields);    
}

file.close();
```

Comment: his bug seemed to also be that he wasn't calling file.open again like you do in your code.

Comment: Thanks all, I need more efforts. there is an error

    error “no matching function for call to ‘QStandardItemModel::appendRow(QStringList&)’”

Comment: @ user289175 : And again, you have to read Qt docs (for example, Qt Assistant). In QStandardItemModel class this is no QStandardItemModel::appendRow(QStringList&) member, but appendRow ( const QList<QStandardItem *> & ) & appendRow ( QStandardItem * ) has.

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't reopen the first file to read data because the first file was never closed.  Close the first file then you will be able to reopen it to read data.

Comment: You can open the same file several times for reading. In this case, the second code does not open it hence the issue. It's a different QFile object.