# I am working to retrieve a particular line from a file in QT. I have done so far but don't know how to access with qbytearray

Tags: qt

I am a newbie.I am working to retrieve a particular line from a file in QT. I have done so far but don't know how to access with qbytearray.

```
void Model::viewFile(const char* name1)
{ 
    QString name = QString::fromStdString(name1);

    QByteArray fileData;
    QFile file("C:\\Qt-Development\\TestApps\\Project1\\Property.txt"); //openin my file
    if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        fileData=file.readAll();
         int len= fileData.length();

      //here I want to serach for the particular word in the file which is in my qbytearray 
    }
}
```

Comment: The title of your post should indicate the question being asked.

Comment: What exactly you want to do? If you need to check whether a word existing in your byte array you can simply use `QByteArray::contains()` function.

Comment: I don't have much experience with QT, but I think the upvoted answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612103/qt-reading-from-a-text-file might help. Its not a duplicate question but it looks helpful. In the while loop it is assigning 1 line at a time to QString line, which is easier to search for text than a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

```
//here I want to serach for the particular word in the file which is in my qbytearray
```

The easiest way would be to create a QString from your byte array and then use the search functions available to QString

```
QString text(fileData);

// see if the text contains a the phrase "some text"
if(text.contains("some text"))
    return true;
```

Or find the position of where a particular string occurs, e.g. "Some text"

```
int pos = text.indexOf("some text");
```

There are various other useful string functions, which you can [read about in the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html)